Viewing a string variable containing a chinese character using breakpoint, it shows its errornous but displays correctly when cout
Here is what im using:
C++
MingW64
Windows 11
VScode
My code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

int main(){
    std::locale::global(std::locale("C"));
    std::string ccstr = "人";
    std::cout<<ccstr;
    return 0;
}

in line 9 I added a breakpoint to view the variable
ccstr outputs correctly, the code and complier runs smoothly, however when I view it through breakpoint ccstr: <incomplete sequence \272>
I would like it to show one chinese character rather than this as I have to manipulate the variable later on
Note:
wstring does not work
I cannot do std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8") and any other chat gpt or something remotely looking like this even with C.UTF-8 because all im getting is:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

most common suggestion from chatgpt and any other seems to not work and atp im thinking if Vscode or Mingw64 is the problem of not supporting UTF-8 or some other
destop screen with the VScode and my code with terminal output

The core of your problem is character encoding. If I modify your code a tiny bit
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
    std::string ccstr = "人";
    std::cout << ccstr.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << strlen(ccstr.c_str()) << '\n';
    std::cout<<ccstr << '\n';
    return 0;
}

I get this output:
stieber@debian:~$ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
3
3
人

So why is this single character string a 3-character string? This is because my system uses UTF-8, and your chinese character is represented by the byte sequence 0xE4 0xBA 0xBA -- 3 bytes.
Things may be different on your system, but that character basically never uses a single-byte encoding.
And it's easy to assume that the debugger simply doesn't care about all this, and only displays printable ASCII characters. Don't worry about it, it's a tool for programmers; end users won't see this...

wait so what if I want to count the number of characters in a str that is mixed with chinese and english, do you know how to count them correctly like lets say 1 chinese char and 2 english it would output 3 rather than 5 because of the stupid character encoding

@Log-e That is exactly the case, and the reason why software needs to be careful when dealing with UTF-8. A standardized way to work with UTF-8 is offered by std::codecvt_utf8 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8), but it's a bit more complicated than just asking .size() of a string, There are probably a number of 3rd party libraries as well.

@Log-e still, as an additional thought, how often do you really need the character count? The only application I can come up with right now is table-printing with a fixed-width font (like on a terminal) -- and, usually, I just cheese out of the character counting by making the thing that can have non-ASCII characters the last column :-) If you don't have a fixed-width font, like in more user-centric applications with an actual GUI, the display-size of a string cannot be determined from character-count anyway...

I was gonna generate a time table with column and rows, so I have to count how many Chinese character and English character cus the Chinese one occupy 2, however the program interpret the size as 3 which makes my table looking like a trashed slum so now I need to find a way to count Chinese character per character but I couldn’t do so. I am doing it in a way where if it’s in the Unicode range which is int 0x(something) and between another int it would count as a Chinese character, do you have a solution to this paradox like the way to count Chinese character?

@Log-e you can always shortcut things a bit, since UTF-8 allows you to determine the length of the sequence from the first byte. So you don't even need to transform the string; you could just go through it and count while you go along, assuming you're getting valid UTF-8. However, even that might not always give you the desired result -- unicode has characters with 0 width, it has characters that print right to left, and it has characters that print over each other... there is no standard C++ way to handle all this. Still, even a simple count will probably improve your display.

It’s just Chinese characters and sometimes the representation is absolutely terrible in my variable which is usually full of werid symbol until it’s outputted, im a new programmer so i have no clue what code or what to do because I’ve never encountered it and I couldn’t find anything online other than some convention to_bytes which doesn’t really work as intended but the output is always correct, is it possible if I can know how many characters are in one file? Because I can output the Chinese character and count how many time the cursor moved in the file until the end no?

codecvt works, cheers m8
std::wstring<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter_obj
